# Создать таймер в Xamarin Android

Tags: android, c#, .net, xamarin, mono

Нужно, чтобы через определенное время бездействия пользователя возвращало в главное меню. Сейчас таймер выглядит так:

```
private void CreateTimer()
{
    backToMainActivityTimer = new System.Timers.Timer();
    backToMainActivityTimer.Interval = 1000;
    backToMainActivityTimer.Elapsed += OnTimedEvent;
    backToMainActivityTimer.Start();
}

//Проверка выводом текста
private void OnTimedEvent(object sender, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
    //Произойдет выход из функции. Текст не появится. 
    //Таймер будет работать дальше
    Toast.MakeText(ApplicationContext, text, ToastLength.Long).Show();
}

//Проверка переключением Layout
private void OnTimedEvent(object sender, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
    //Приложение замрет и не будет реагировать
    SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);
}
```

Не удается вывести сообщение или переключить Layout.
Как правильно сделать таймер в Xamarin Android?

Comment: замирает на чем именно?

Comment: @LexHobbit замирает при попытке переключить Layout. При попытке вывести сообщение через Toast.MakeText сразу вылетает из функции, но приложение продолжает работать

Comment: на будущее, четче описывайте проблему с детализацией(как, например, сейчас у вас выглядит вопрос), тогда выше вероятность, что вы получите быстрый и правильный ответ

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Поставьте в инициализации таймера

```
backToMainActivityTimer.AutoReset = false;
```

Чтобы работал `SetContentView` и `Toast`, нужно вызывать их используя `RunOnUiThread`:

```
private void OnTimedEvent(object sender, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
RunOnUiThread(() =>
            {
                SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);
            });
}
```

Comment: Это мне не помогло

Comment: @mirypoko обновил

Comment: Заработало, спасибо большое! Может вы еще подскажите, есть ли какое-то событие, которое срабатывает когда пользователь что-то пишет/нажимает и т.д., чтобы сбрасывать таймер возвращения, если пользователь работает с устройством?

Comment: @mirypoko почитайте про onUserInteraction https://developer.xamarin.com/api/member/Android.App.Activity.OnUserInteraction()/